# Identify The Day of the Doctor old shots

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification, the-day-of-the-doctor

This will be pretty hard, challenging and probably only for the real hard Whovians.

I watched [the thirteen Doctors scene from **The Day of the Doctor**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e71KWwE5Fk) again. I assume that all of the old Doctor scenes (and I would say also the 9th Doctor scene) are from the archive (correct me if they are not)

They are mostly very short and I am curious, from which episodes they come from.